# Botão active de acordo com a página

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tenho um conjunto de divs abaixo do header (cardiacas, abdominais, faciais...), cada um com o seu respectivo link, usando os mesmos nomes.
Preciso que quando eu selecione um dos botões, ele se torne "ativo", mesmo com a troca da página, pois cada botão tem a sua própria página.
Ex: estou na página "Faciais", ela está ativa, abaixo tenho uma lista Collapse com alguns conteúdos, com o primeiro item também ativo, Clico em "Vocais" o botão ao lado, a página seria trocada, o botão "Vocais" e o primeiro item da lista abaixo ficariam ativos, estou usando dois scripts JS, um para ativar os botões e o collapse, e outro para esconder um collapse e mostrar outro dependendo do item selecionado na lista, agradeço desde já a ajuda!
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```html
<div id="botao-cardiacas-2">
 <a class="link1" href="http://localhost/hospital-iphone/cardiacas/">
 <img class="especialidades-padding img-container" src="http://localhost/hospital-iphone/wp-content\themes\hospitaldoiphone\img\cardiacas.png"/>
 <p class="texto-especialidades-2">
  Cardíacas
 </p>
 <p class="texto-especialidades-sub-2">
  Problemas com bateria
 </p>
 </a>
</div>

<div id="botao-abdominais-2">
 <a class="link1" href="http://localhost/hospital-iphone/cardiacas/">
 <img class="img-container" src="http://localhost/hospital-iphone/wp-content\themes\hospitaldoiphone\img\abdominais.png"/>
 <p class="texto-especialidades-2">
  Abdominais
 </p>
 <p class="texto-especialidades-sub-2">
  Problemas com botão Home
 </p>
 </a>
</div>

<div id="botao-faciais-2">
 <a class="link1" href="http://localhost/hospital-iphone/cardiacas/">
 <img class="img-container" src="http://localhost/hospital-iphone/wp-content\themes\hospitaldoiphone\img\faciais.png"/>
 <p class="texto-especialidades-2">
  Faciais
 </p>
 <p class="texto-especialidades-sub-2">
  Problemas com a tela
 </p>
 </a>
</div>

<div id="botao-vocais-2">
 <a class="link1" href="http://localhost/hospital-iphone/cardiacas/">
 <img class="img-container" src="http://localhost/hospital-iphone/wp-content\themes\hospitaldoiphone\img\vocais.png"/>
 <p class="texto-especialidades-2">
  Vocais
 </p>
 <p class="texto-especialidades-sub-2">
  Falantes e microfones
 </p>
 </a>
</div>

<div id="botao-estetica-2">
 <a class="link1" href="http://localhost/hospital-iphone/cardiacas/">
 <img class="img-container" src="http://localhost/hospital-iphone/wp-content\themes\hospitaldoiphone\img\estetica.png"/>
 <p class="texto-especialidades-2">
  Estética
 </p>
 <p class="texto-especialidades-sub-2">
  Tampa traseira
 </p>
 </a>
</div>

<div id="botao-cognitiva-2">
 <a class="link1" href="http://localhost/hospital-iphone/cardiacas/">
 <img class="especialidades-padding img-container" src="http://localhost/hospital-iphone/wp-content\themes\hospitaldoiphone\img\cognitiva.png"/>
 <p class="texto-especialidades-2">
  Cognitiva
 </p>
 <p class="texto-especialidades-sub-2">
  Antenas Wifi e GSM
 </p>
 </a>
</div>

<div id="botao-visuais-2">
 <a class="link1" href="http://localhost/hospital-iphone/cardiacas/">
 <img class="especialidades-padding img-container" src="http://localhost/hospital-iphone/wp-content\themes\hospitaldoiphone\img\visual.png"/>
 <p class="texto-especialidades-2">
  Visuais
 </p>
 <p class="texto-especialidades-sub-2">
  Câmeras
 </p>
 </a>
</div>

div id="botao-respiratorio-2">
 <a class="link1" href="http://localhost/hospital-iphone/cardiacas/">
 <img class="especialidades-padding img-container" src="http://localhost/hospital-iphone/wp-content\themes\hospitaldoiphone\img\respiratorio.png"/>
 <p class="texto-especialidades-2">
  Respiratório
 </p>
 <p class="texto-especialidades-sub-2">
  Dados e sistema operacional
 </p>
 </a>
</div>

<div id="botao-outros">
 <a class="link1" href="http://localhost/hospital-iphone/cardiacas/">
 <img class="img-container" src="http://localhost/hospital-iphone/wp-content\themes\hospitaldoiphone\img\outros.png"/>
 <p class="texto-especialidades-2">
  Outros
 </p>
 <p class="texto-especialidades-sub-2">
  Outros serviços
 </p>
 </a>
</div>
```

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.list-left').click(function() {
        $(this).closest('ul').find('li').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    });
});

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#botao-cardiacas-2').click(function() {
        $(this).closest('ul').find('li').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
function id( el ){
        return document.getElementById( el );
}
function hide_all(){
        var divs = id('content1').getElementsByTagName('div');
        for( var i=0; i<divs.length; i++ )
        {
                divs[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
}
/* http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/event.shtml */
function disablelink( e ){
        var evt = window.event || e
        if (evt.preventDefault) //supports preventDefault?
                evt.preventDefault()
        else //IE browser
                return false
}
window.onload = function(){
        hide_all();
        var as = id('content1').getElementsByTagName('a');
        for( var i=0; i<as.length; i++ )
        {
                as[i].onclick = function( e ){
                        hide_all();
                        var id_el = this.href.split('#')
                       
                        id( id_el[1] ).style.display = 'block';                
                        return disablelink( e );
                }
        }
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content1" class="container-content container-height">
<ul id="test-content" class="no-padding">
<li class="list-left list1" ><a href="#item1">Reposição LCD</a></li>        
<div id="item1" class="item1">
 <p class="titulo">Reposição LDC</p>
 <p class="sub-titulo">Cirurgia facial</p>
 <p class="texto">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.</p>
<img scr="#"/>
</div>
 
<li class="list-left list2"><a href="#item2">Reposição TOUCH</a></li> 
<div id="item2" class="item2">
 <p class="titulo">Reposição TOUCH</p>
 <p class="sub-titulo">Cirurgia facial</p>
 <p class="texto">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariaore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.</p>
</div>
 
<li class="list-left list3"><a href="#item3">Reconexão Display / Frontal</a></li>
<div id="item3" class="item3">
 <p class="titulo">Reposição Display</p>
 <p class="sub-titulo">Cirurgia facial</p>
 <p class="texto">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in , sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.</p>
</div>
 
<li class="list-left list4"><a href="#item4">Montagem MO</a></li> 
<div id="item4" class="item4">
 <p class="titulo">Montagem MO</p>
 <p class="sub-titulo">Cirurgia facial</p>
 <p class="texto">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.</p>
</div>
 
<li class="list-left list5"><a href="#item5">Reposição Display Frontal</a></li>
<div id="item5" class="item5">
 <p class="titulo">Reposição Display</p>
 <p class="sub-titulo">Cirurgia facial</p>
 <p class="texto">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.</p>
</div>
 
<li class="list-left list6"><a href="#item6">Aplicação Peliculas</a></li>
<div id="item6" class="item6">
 <p class="titulo">Aplicação de Peliculas</p>
 <p class="sub-titulo">Cirurgia facial</p>
 <p class="texto">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.</p>
</div>
 
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Ao carregar a página é recarregada ou só altera a div com as informações pretendidas?

Comment: por mim pode ser das duas formas, o que você achar melhor

Comment: Ao clicar em um botão, a página é recarregada ou tudo é feito de forma dinâmica sem reload da página?

Comment: os botões de cima podem recarregar a página, só os de baixo que não, mas se não carregasse a página também ficaria bom.

Answer (score 0):

Se não houver recarregamento de página, você pode realizar da seguinte maneira, apenas adaptando o exemplo à sua necessidade. Aconselho usar o bootstrap para obter o efeito de accordion pretendido. Envolva suas `divs` de conteúdo em um `panel-group` e realiza o `accordion`, nos botões, você irá colocar o `id` das `divs` que serão os alvos para a realização do efeito.

Para saber mais, veja [aqui](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion) a documentação do bootstrap sobre accordions.

```js
$('button').click( function(){
    var alvo = $(this); //captura o botao clicado
    $('button').removeClass('ativo') // remove a classe dos demais botoes
    alvo.addClass('ativo');// adiciona a classe ao botao alvo
    
})
```

```css
.ativo {
   background-color: red
}
```

```html
<button class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#alvo1" aria-expanded="false" > Exemplo botão 1 </button>

<button class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#alvo2" aria-expanded="false" > Exemplo botão 2 </button>
<button class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#alvo3" aria-expanded="false"> Exemplo botão 3 </button>
<button class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#alvo4" aria-expanded="false"> Exemplo botão 4 </button>


<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">  
    
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        
          Eu sou o alvo 1
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="alvo1" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        
          Eu sou o alvo 2
       
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="alvo2" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        
          Eu sou o alvo 3
       
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="alvo3" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        
          Eu sou o alvo 4
       
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="alvo4" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"> </script>
```

Deixei o código comentado, caso houver dúvidas pode perguntar.

Comment: isso eu já consigo fazer, o problema é fazer com que o os botões de cima troquem a lista de baixo que exibe os conteúdos, não tenho ideia de como proceder

Comment: @Gouper editei a resposta, dê uma olhada...